# React router - reloading the page while navigating

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I am using [ReactGo](https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo) boiler-plate to develop an application. 
Using react-router for navigating through the site and this is the code,

```jsx
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

<Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/login" component={SignIn} pageType="checkout" />
</Route>
```

and this is the App component,

```jsx
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const rounteProps = this.props.children.props.route;
    const pageType = rounteProps.pageType;

    return (<div className="app">
      {pageType === 'checkout' ? (<CheckoutHeader />) : (<Header />)}
      <div className="grid-wrapper site-page content--centered">
        <main className="grid grid--space-y site-main">
          {this.props.children}
        </main>
        <Footer />
        <Loader />
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

I am using ***pageType*** for conditional rendering of ***Header component*** as there are 2 different headers I have. This works fine with all the routes which do not have any pageType / common pageType.

However when I go to the page ***/login*** which has ***pageType=checkout***. It reloads the entire page (and as per my observation it loads the component twice). Don't know why is this happening? Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Are you doing any setState in componentDidMount() in SignIn component?